# Cross browser HTML5 iFrame

Tags: jquery, dom, html, cross-browser

Right now I have an iFrame object with the seamless attribute which looks perfect,

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=400&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35" seamless></iframe>
```

with a couple css attributes

```
iframe {
  overflow: hidden !important;
  border: none !important;
  width: 400px;
  height: 35px;
  background-color: #cce0da;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Then for Internet Explorer I have some fallback attributes applied with some jQuery

```
$(function() {
  $('iframe', '.ie')
    .attr('allowTransparency', 'true')
    .attr('frameBorder', '0')
    .attr('scrolling', 'no');
});
```

What I end up with is a transparent iFrame in IE with an unnecessary border.

Maybe there is a problem with my code? Maybe my DOM manipulation of the frameBorder attribute doesn't render after document.ready?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a "frameborder" attribute directly in the markup...

```
<iframe frameborder="0"
```

Comment: Ha, awesome and funny, just stumbled on that too. Thanks!

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there is an alternate way to get this attribute in the dom and make it render. jQuery and conditional comments don't do it. Wanting my document to validate in HTML5, frameborder is obsolete. YIKES

Comment: Yes, it is certainly a deprecated attribute.  I think you have a choice to make: validation or proper rendering.  I'd say the choice is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Scuse me for my english, i use this code in script js

This in HEAD section

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script> 
 <script src="myscrip"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

This is my script

```
jQuery("iframe").each(function() {

  var copy = jQuery(this).clone();

  jQuery(copy).attr("frameborder", '0');
  jQuery(copy).attr("scrolling", 'no');

  jQuery(copy).replaceAll(this);

});
```

is preferible add script in the

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
```

small problem is little refresh that resolve with

```
 iframe css=display:none
 add in my script function .show after replaceAll
```

Comment: used this but chained it: $(copy).attr({frameborder: '0',scrolling: 'no'}).replaceAll(this);

Answer (score 0):

If you want your document to validate in HTML5, you can use your original method. There's several things you need to do to make it work in IE < 9:

1) Clone the iframe, set the attributes, and then append to a container. Or create the iframe element from scratch. IE just won't let you set the attributes afterwards.

2) Remove the original iframe.

```
    $('#facebook-like iframe').clone().attr({ 'frameBorder': '0', 'allowTransparency': 'true', 'scrolling': 'no' }).appendTo('#facebook-like');
    $('#facebook-like iframe').first().remove();
```